# Puebla Airport to and from Puebla

Tags: airport-transfer, mexico, puebla, pbc

What options are available for transportation between the Puebla airport and somewhere in the historical center of the city itself? How much should a single person expect to pay? And where do I find this at the airport itself and also on the way back from the historical center?

Bonus points if this also applies between the Puebla airport and Cholula as I may decide to go or get back from there instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [puebla-mexico.com](http://www.puebla-mexico.com/transit/):

> ... upon arrival, hire an official taxi for 250 to 300 pesos at the
> stand inside the terminal or arrange for private pick-up/shuttle
> service in advance.
>
> ....
>
> . The majority of cabs in Puebla are not metered, so you’ll likely
> have to negotiate the fare. For the best deal, tell the driver where
> you’re headed and agree on a price before you get into the cab....

Comment: The official price of 250 pesos is given at the airport on a coupon and you hand this to the taxi driver.

Answer (score 2):

From [another user online](http://www.world-airport-codes.com/mexico/hermanos-serdan-international-6075.html) (albeit a couple of years ago) (in the comments at the bottom of the page):

> Local buses and taxis available. For 6 pesos (60 cents) the local bus
>   can take you just about anywhere you want. You need to negotiate price
>   with taxis as they do not use meters. 
>   Anywhere from 100 pesos ($10) and up.

Comment: -1 for blindly pasting potentially obsolete information